# Tengo problema en la ordenación de la vista Index cuando hay columnas que traen ID

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Use este  [ARTICULO](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) para realizar la ordenación, filtrado y paginación de las vistas Index, y aquellas vistas que traen datos de otra tabla como ID hacen que toda la ordenación de la vista funcione mal.

Les dejo el código a ver si me pueden ayudar.

> CÓDIGO:(CONTROLADOR)

```
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)

 ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

            var vehicles = from s in db.Vehicles
                           select s;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                vehicles = vehicles.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchString)
                                       || s.TypeVehicles.Description.Contains(searchString)
                                       || s.Groups.Description.Contains(searchString)
                                       || s.State.Description.Contains(searchString));
            }
            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    vehicles = vehicles.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    vehicles = vehicles.OrderBy(s => s.TypeVehicles.Description);
                    vehicles = vehicles.OrderBy(s => s.Groups.Description);
                    vehicles = vehicles.OrderBy(s => s.State.Description);
                    vehicles = vehicles.OrderBy(s => s.Kmh);
                    vehicles = vehicles.OrderBy(s => s.PromLitres);
                    vehicles = vehicles.OrderBy(s => s.TotalPay);
                    break;
                case "date_desc":
                    vehicles = vehicles.OrderByDescending(s => s.TypeVehicles.Description);
                    vehicles = vehicles.OrderByDescending(s => s.Groups.Description);
                    vehicles = vehicles.OrderByDescending(s => s.State.Description);
                    vehicles = vehicles.OrderByDescending(s => s.Kmh);
                    vehicles = vehicles.OrderByDescending(s => s.PromLitres);
                    vehicles = vehicles.OrderByDescending(s => s.TotalPay);
                    break;
                default:
                    vehicles = vehicles.OrderBy(s => s.Name);
                    break;
            }

            int pageSize = 8;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(vehicles.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

> CÓDIGO:(VISTA)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Vehicles", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Buscar por nombre: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Buscar</button>
    </p>
}


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("NOMBRE", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("TIPO DE VEHÍCULO", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("GRUPO", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("ESTADO", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("KILÓMETROS", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("PROMEDIO KM x L", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("TOTAL GASTADO", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor borra las imágenes, copia y pega el código, sino muy difícil ayudarte

Comment: Ahí esta corregido, necesito de tu ayuda por favor